# How to reset samsung edge s6?

Tags: samsung, factory-reset

My Samsung has crashed, I can see that it's on but it does not respond to any button clicks nor shuts down

[Tried this](http://www.hardreset.info/devices/samsung/samsung-g925r-galaxy-s6-edge/#softreset) and it does not work.

How to reset Samsung edge s6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

You need to press power button and then volume down button and hold them for some time.

Comment: Or hold the power button for ten seconds.

Comment: @DanB that was first thing I did - didn't work.

Comment: Oh. Well, that's bizarre, it works on mine.